# Problema com site responsivo ao abrir em um celular

Tags: bootstrap-4, layout-responsivo

Olá, criei um site com 2 efeitos Paralax para praticar essa funcionalidade via bootstrap. Como é um site apenas front end, gostaria de testar ele pelo celular mesmo (sem funções de alterar tamanho da plataforma pelo navegador).
Então eu abri, copiei os arquivos deste projeto para o meu celular para testar o funcionamento direto no celular, porém ele não mostra as imagens e muito menos acessa as páginas de estilo e etc. Em outras palavras, ele mostra só a estrutura html, sem aplicação do css.

Obs: o parallax é só com CSS mesmo. 
Algumas dúvidas gerais: 
 eu preciso de algum app específico para compilar o bootstrap no cel? 
 entendo que preciso reorganizar os links para fazer a chamada local correta na pasta os arquivos do cel, mas como?
Lembrando que eu quero abrir este arquivo diretamente pelo cel para testar.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/estilo.css">
        <title>Parallax</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section class="header-site">
        <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <h1 class="text-center">BEM-VINDO</h1>
                        <p class="lead text-center text-dark text-uppercase" style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

                        <p class="text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Cadastre-se</a>                        
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div> 

        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content-site">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Donec eget consectetur nibh, quis aliquam odio. Ut lobortis luctus sollicitudin.</h1>

                    <p class="text-center">Quisque malesuada malesuada lorem, a lobortis libero finibus sed. Suspendisse sem nisl, porta tristique leo eu, rhoncus mollis ligula. Integer nunc tellus, condimentum faucibus cursus at, fermentum ut ligula. Donec maximus gravida est, ac elementum felis consectetur pretium. Cras sed luctus massa, et facilisis libero. Etiam tincidunt lacus quis placerat ultrices. </p>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card">

                        <img src="img/01.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            <h3>Etiam justo ipsum egestas.</h3>
                            <p class="card-text" style="height:225px">asellus id metus nec eros mollis tristique. Donec velit quam, congue vitae metus at, ultrices posuere urna. Aenean euismod justo a quam accumsan suscipit. Nam accumsan purus eu tellus pulvinar sodales quis in erat eros.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card">

                        <img src="img/02.jpg" class="card-img-top"  style="height:350px">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            <h3>Quisque cursus dolor vitae sollicitudin egestas.</h3>
                            <p class="card-text" style="height:190px">asellus id metus nec eros mollis tristique. Donec velit quam, congue vitae metus at, ultrices posuere urna. Aenean euismod justo a quam accumsan suscipit. Nam accumsan purus eu tellus pulvinar sodales quis in erat.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card">

                        <img src="img/03.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            <h3>Pellentesque egestas massa non ultricies tincidunt.</h3>
                            <p class="card-text" style="height:160px">asellus id metus nec eros mollis tristique. Donec velit quam, congue vitae metus at, ultrices posuere urna. Aenean euismod justo a quam accumsan suscipit. Nam accumsan purus eu tellus pulvinar sodales quis in erat.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>    

        </div>

    </section>
    <br><br>
    <section class="content-2">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Nunc quis sodales turpis.</h1>
                    <p class="lead text-center"  style="font-weight:bold;">Phasellus id metus nec eros mollis tristique. Donec velit quam, congue vitae metus at, ultrices posuere urna. Aenean euismod justo a quam accumsan suscipit. Nam accumsan purus eu tellus pulvinar sodales quis in erat.</p>               

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="footer">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <p class="text-center">Nullam condimentum, nisi non vehicula malesuada, est est sagittis leo, id dignissim arcu augue sed ligula.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript
    jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS 
    atenção aqui. se n der o efeito q quero preciso trocar o link-->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.header-site{<br>
    background-image:url(file:///E|/Programas%20em%20execucao/wamp/www/aulas/paralaxTeste/img/galaxy-wallpapers-5.jpg);<br>
    background-position: center top;<br>
    background-repeat:no-repeat;<br>
    background-size:cover;<br>
    background-attachment:fixed;<br>
    color:#fff;<br>
    padding-top:300px;<br>
    padding-bottom:300px;}<br>

.content-site{<br>
    padding-top:200px;<br>
    padding-bottom:200px;}<br>

.content-2{<br>
    background-image:url(file:///E|/Programas%20em%20execucao/wamp/www/aulas/paralaxTeste/img/Shadow-of-the-Colossus-2-.jpg);<br>
    background-position: center top;<br>
    background-repeat:no-repeat;<br>
    background-size:cover;<br>
    background-attachment:fixed;<br>
    color:#fff;<br>
    padding-top:300px;<br>
    padding-bottom:300px;}<br>

.footer{<br>
    background-color:#333;<br>
    color:#fff;<br>
    padding-top:250px;<br>
    padding-bottom:250px;}<br>
```

Comment: porque você não usa a ferramenta do Chrome para emular como ficaria o layout em mobile?
Aperta `f12` depois `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `M`

Comment: Foi como eu disse ali entre parênteses, as funções pra teste de plataforma via chrome como tu sugeriu eu já fiz, é q a ideia é colocar o site no celular para mostrar em uma entrevista de estágio, por isso queria que abrisse diretamente no cel :)

Comment: Acho que as vezes o https://phonegap.com/ pode te ajudar. Mas o melhor mesmo seria vc colocar seus arquivos em um FTP, mesmo que seja um GitPages, ou em qq outro FTP free. Ou (não sei se existe isso). Instala um servidor local tipo Wamp ou Xamp no seu Cel e coloca os arquivos lá etc